# ASP.NET SqlDataReader

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm currently creating a website with different account types to log-in. For example an admin will be redirected to the admin page and a member to another page etc. I'm retrieving their account types in my database using a `SqlDataReader` but it's no success.

Here's my class:

```
public bool searchAccount()
{
    using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    using (SqlCommand searchCmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchAccount", myCon))
    {
        bool found = false;

        myCon.Open();

        searchCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        searchCmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user;
        searchCmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pass;

        using (SqlDataReader dr = searchCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                user = dr.GetString(0);
                fName = dr.GetString(2);
                lName = dr.GetString(3);
                accType = dr.GetString(4);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        myCon.Close();
        return found;
    }
}
```

Here's my SQL statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spSearchAccount
    @user nvarchar(50),
    @pass nvarchar(50)
AS
    SELECT 
       tblAccount.username, tblLogin.username, 
       tblAccount.firstName, tblAccount.lastName, 
       tblAccount.accountType
    FROM 
       tblAccount, tblLogin
    WHERE 
       tblAccount.username = @user
       AND tblLogin.username = @user
       AND tblLogin.password = @pass

    RETURN 0
```

Here's my code in the form:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myData.User = txtUser.Text;
    myData.Pass = txtPass.Text;

    if (myData.searchAccount())
    {
        Session["username"] = myData.User;
        Session["firstName"] = myData.FName;
        Session["lastName"] = myData.LName;
        Session["accountType"] = myData.AccType;

        if (myData.AccType == "Admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
        }
        else if (myData.AccType == "Faculty")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Faculty.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Member.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
        Response.Write("<script> alert('Invalid Username or Password')</script>");
}
```

It always goes to the member page even though I log-in using an admin account.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: `while (dr.Read()) { ... break; }` Why would you do this?

Comment: `searchCmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pass;` Why would you do THIS?? `AddWithValue` is a thing. So are password hashes.

Comment: _it's no success._ please clarify. Did you get an error message? No user found? If you run that procedure with the same parameters in Sql Server Management Studio did you get a return value?

Comment: @ta.speot.is the while statement is used to search for the records in the database, if it didn't see any accounts, it will go to else statement which is 'Invalid username or Password'

Comment: You don't need a loop. Simply `if (dr.Read())` will suffice.

Comment: @AldrinRamirez probably he is saying that you shouldn't have that while in the first place. You should find zero or one record for a particular user/password combination, not two or more. This should be guaranteed by an unique index on these two fields in your db.

Comment: @Steve I'm not getting an error message, it just didn't go to the if statement where it says if the user is admin, it will be redirected to the admin page but it just go to the member page even the user is an admin

Comment: @AldrinRamirez case sensitivity problem? `"Admin" != "admin"`

Comment: @Steve  it's not sire

Comment: If I were you, I won't do it that way. Better if you use a Membership and create roles, then assign each user to its specific role/s.

Comment: Method aside, did you step through searchAccount?  If so, are you getting the values you expect, particularly for accType, which I assume you are using to tell whether it is "Admin" or "Faculty".  I don't see the properties defined, so if you are getting what you want, did you break after the call to searchAccount() and make sure that the properties are set to the values you read from the database?  There are a bunch of places where there could be problems.  If the data selected isn't unique (as the other Steve pointed out), you could be running into problems there.